# MATLAB only calculates the final data

Tags: matlab

I wrote the below code to calculate the multilayer reflection, each time the new matrix should be multiplied from the left side to give the final matrix. When I plot it, it only gives the final value and doesn't calculate former data, so the graph is uniform.
Thanks in advance

```
%This program is for calculating the total reflection from multilayer of
%epidermis-dermis-blood by considering air as the initial medium
clc;
l=(0.3:0.03:3).*1.0E-3;%milimeter
e_inf=[1.0,3.0,5.5,2.1,1.0]; %Air-Epidermis-Dermis-Whole Blood_air(for reflection)
e_1=[1.0,58,58,130,1.0];
e_2=[1.0,3.6,5.6,3.8,1.0];
t_1=[0.1,9.4,9.4,14.4,0.1]*(1.0E-12);
t_2=[0.1,0.18,0.18,0.1,0.1]*(1.0E-12);
d=[2,0.2,0.002,0.05]*1.0E-3; %Thickness of air-epidermis-dermis-blood
Q=zeros(length(l),5);
for x=1:1:length(l)
    M_TOT=ones(2,2);%for matrix calculation 
    l_0=l(x); %wavelength
    w=((2*pi)*(3.0E8))./l_0; %angular frequency
    for z=1:1:4 %Four matrices should be calculated
    Z=z+1; %each time two refractive indices should be calculated
    %%%% refractive index%%%
    epsilon_r_z=e_inf(1,z)+((e_1(1,z)-e_2(1,z))./(1+(w.*t_1(1,z)).^2))...
        +((e_2(1,z)-e_inf(1,z))./(1+(w.*t_2(1,z)).^2));
    epsilon_im_z=((e_1(1,z)-e_2(1,z)).*(w.*t_1(1,z)))./(1+(w.*t_1(1,z)).^2)...
        +((e_2(1,z)-e_inf(1,z)).*((w.*t_2(1,z)))./(1+(w.*t_2(1,z)).^2));
    n_1_z=sqrt((sqrt((epsilon_r_z).^2+(epsilon_im_z).^2)+epsilon_r_z)./2);
    n_2_z=sqrt((sqrt((epsilon_r_z).^2+(epsilon_im_z).^2)-epsilon_r_z)./2);
    n_z=n_1_z-1j*n_2_z; %Refractive Index of first layer
    
    epsilond_r_Z=e_inf(1,Z)+((e_1(1,Z)-e_2(1,Z))./(1+(w.*t_1(1,Z)).^2))...
        +((e_2(1,Z)-e_inf(1,Z))./(1+(w.*t_2(1,Z)).^2));
    epsilond_im_Z=((e_1(1,Z)-e_2(1,Z)).*(w.*t_1(1,Z)))./(1+(w.*t_1(1,Z)).^2)...
        +((e_2(1,Z)-e_inf(1,Z)).*((w.*t_2(1,Z)))./(1+(w.*t_2(1,Z)).^2));
    n_1_Z=sqrt((sqrt((epsilond_r_Z).^2+(epsilond_im_Z).^2)+epsilond_r_Z)./2);
    n_2_Z=sqrt((sqrt((epsilond_r_Z).^2+(epsilond_im_Z).^2)-epsilond_r_Z)./2);
    n_Z=n_1_Z-1j*n_2_Z; %Refractive Index of second layer
    
    phi_z=(n_z).*(2*pi/l_0).*d(1,z);%Phase
    r_TE_21_z=(n_Z-n_z)./(n_Z+n_z); %For simplicicty
    
    M_TE_z=[exp(-2j*phi_z) r_TE_21_z; r_TE_21_z.*exp(-2j*phi_z) 1]; %Matrix
   
    M_TOT=M_TE_z*M_TOT; %Total Matrix
    
    end
    Final= y_1*M_TOT; %Final Result
    der_1=-Final(2,1); %2*1
    der_2=Final(2,2);  %2*2
    r_12=(der_1)./(der_2);%r_12
    Ref=abs(r_12).^2;     %R
    
    Q(x,1)=l_0*1.0E3;
    Q(x,2)=Ref;
end

plot(Q(:,1),Q(:,2))
title('Multilayer Reflection','Fontsize',14)
set(gcf,'color','w');
ylabel('Reflection','Fontsize',14)
xlabel('\lambda(mm)','Fontsize',14)
```

Comment: It doesn't run like this - what is `y1`?

Comment: y_1=1. I used it to calculate some coefficients but I forgot remove it in this code.